# C# send values on network with UTP

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am trying to develop a C# UTP server in order to send a list of string `sList`. This is continuously filled by another thread. My aspected software behavior is to get a client on the network and send each information.

Here the method:

```
    internal static void MyUDPSocket()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        socket.Bind(ip);

        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);

        while (true)
        {
            if (sList.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sList[0]);
                    socket.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, Remote);
                    sList.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                catch (FormatException e) { }
                catch (System.ArgumentNullException en) { }

            }
        }
    }
```

Anyway, when I launch the software, C# return an Exception (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException) on `socket.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, Remote)` and it say that there is not a required address in the context.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a destination address with INADDR_ANY, with a port of 0.  You can't do that.

Comment: You want to use INADDR_ANY:0 when doing a recvFrom

Comment: I am sorry, it is a copy and paste error. I edit the code in the main post

Comment: Again @youngz you are sending to IPAddress.Any.  Technically speaking it is an unspecified IP address.  How would sentTo() know where to send to?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry. Now I understand what you mean. Do you know a method in order to broadcast the message at each client in listening?

Comment: That's a whole different topic.  Generally a "server" doesn't broadcast anything in regards to "Hey I'm listening".  For that you could use a ZeroConf application (like Bonjour) to that a remote client could query to get the ip address of "listeners".  You just want to set up the server to listen for udp packets FROM INADDR_ANY:ANYPORT